# How to fix a column inplace after performing groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My data has some issue and I want to fix this as defined in the function `fixseq`. I am looking for efficient way to fix column `B`. This column can't have negative number and if does, I need to shift the number so that it starts from 0.

```
def fixseq(tmp):
    print(tmp)
    if tmp['B'][0] < 0:
        tmp['B'] = tmp['B'] +   abs(tmp['B'][0])
    return tmp

data = {
    'id': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    'number': [-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

Output:

```
id  number
0   A   0
1   A   1
2   A   2
3   A   3
4   A   4
5   A   5
6   B   0
7   B   1
8   B   2
```

I did try `groupby` followed by `apply` but keeps on getting error. Tried with map as well. I can process each group at a time and accumulate in list and finally concatenate it to get the work done but I do not want to do this heavy lifting. I am sure there is some better way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, just subtract the min per group with [`groupby.transform('min')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['number'] -= df.groupby('id')['number'].transform('min')

# or for a new column
# df['new'] = df['number'] - df.groupby('id')['number'].transform('min')
```

If your can have groups that start greater than 0 (e.g. `[5, 6, 7]`) and don't want to affect those, combine with [`clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html):

```
df['number'] -= df.groupby('id')['number'].transform('min').clip(upper=0)
```

Output:

```
  id  number
0  A       0
1  A       1
2  A       2
3  A       3
4  A       4
5  A       5
6  B       0
7  B       1
8  B       2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df["fixed_number"] = (
    df.groupby("id")["number"].apply(lambda n: n + abs(min(0, n.min()))).values
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  id  number  fixed_number
0  A      -4             0
1  A      -3             1
2  A      -2             2
3  A      -1             3
4  A       0             4
5  A       1             5
6  B       0             0
7  B       1             1
8  B       2             2
```